# How to delete files in multiple unknown folders from a single bat file?

Tags: batch-file, directory, delete-file

Suppose I don't know names of all the folders in a directory. I want to delete all the .exe file in those folders from a single bat file. What will be the command? Is it possible?

```
cd ?
del *.exe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do

```
del /s *.exe
```

/S stands for delete from all Subfolders (DELTREE)

Answer (score 3):

Using FOR to iterate over directories:

```
for /d %i in (*.*) do del %i\*.exe
```

Comment: If you're going to use this command inside a batch file you need to use double %% signs